# Cambiar url al hacer scroll sin recargar pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

He visto paginas de feed news, que muestran un articulo, pero cuando scroleas hasta terminar de leer, automáticamente abajo se carga otro articulo, y cuando sigues para leer ese articulo, la url cambia y la página ni siquiera se recarga, es genial para navegaciones continuas.

esta es la [pagina](https://www.techwalla.com/13718649/google-fit-is-now-available-on-ios)

solo encontre esto:

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

tendría que agregar eso a un evento de on scroll?
quizás requiera de algunas tecnología más. atento a sus sugerencias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías utilizar una librería para no molestarte tanto en ello: https://infinite-scroll.com/

Aquí hay un ejemplo del scroll infinito con el cambio de url: https://infinite-scroll.com/demo/full-page/